# how to choose the same theme for each store-view

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, rwd-theme

I'm new to magento and i have a store contains 2 store views.
I want to use the default theme (RWD) for both store views.
But each store have its own layout and alignment.
So i need 2 copies from (RWD)theme for each store view.
I tried to make a copy of the (RWD) CSS file but didn't know where to locate it.

so how to make this copy and point each store to the correct theme?

Answer (score 0):

Just need to update configuration settings:

Inside `System->Configuration->General->Design->Theme`

Set `same values` for each store view.

**Added :**

As you said need different files for each stores also. So you can do this way:

1. Create copy of theme folders inside `design` & `skin` folders. Ex. `rwd_store1` & `rwd_store2`
2. Now follow the same way set those themes as per store in configuration.

Feel free to upvote if helped. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.i need the same theme for both stores .But not the same theme files.(lets say there is a component in store A and i give it align to right,i don't want the same component at store B also align to right)

Comment: Please check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You Don't need to give two theme for each store view or store level.

At global scope you can set default theme, and store level you can check the `use Website` and Website level you check the `Global scope` checkbox check your job is done.

Now global scope value renders always and magento always pick the global scope values only.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that makes the 2 store view pointing to the same RWD theme. I need each store to have its own theme files.(RWD for both stores but different files so i can create different style and layout for each store)

Comment: ok for `current package name` you can set at global leval and other thing you can store at your store level

Comment: @bod You got your solution or not